# Accessing a WebService using a C# Script

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis

I am currently building an SSIS integration package and as part of this I need to access a webservice. Does anybody know of any C# code that can be used to provide variable values to a webservice and then also GET the value that the web service returns.

The SSIS Web Service Task isn't quite as dynamic as I need it to be. The parameters I need to provide are:

• serverName

• databaseName

• hardwareFingerprint

• userName

Comment: please give details about the web service. what is the data format that it uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead adding a Script Task. Within the code editor, right click on References and choose 'Add Web Reference'. Type in the web service endpoint URI, give it a name local to your project and click 'Add Reference'.

Within your ScriptMain.cs file, add a using statement to point to your new web reference, instantiate the service and make the call.

Some example code:

```
using Company.WebServices;

namespace ST_abcdef.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            WebService1 webService1 = new WebService1();
            var result = webService1.methodA("param1", "param2");
            // process result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the script seems to complete ok. But nothing seems to happening with the values I pass to the webservice. Basically the webservice does something with the values and then writes to a SQL table but Im not seeing anything in my SQL Table. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any logs you can check to see if the web service is being called or if it fails before this point?

Comment: Im going to try and find that out now, another interesting twist is that the webservice accepts objects as the params, so I am thinking I am going to need to create an object, set the object with a string value and then pass the object into the webservice method

Comment: Sounds like you have it nailed. Remember to make the object serializable!

Comment: I wish I had nailed it, nothing seems to be creating in my SQL table. Trying to get access to some logs now, if they exist. Is there anything I should be replace the process result part of your code with or should the two lines be enough to send the values to the webservice?

Comment: Nothing in the logs either, looks like the service isnt even being called

Comment: No the `var result = webService1.methodA("param1", "param2");` line is all you need to make the call. Are you debugging locally? If so, try installing a packet sniffer such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and seeing if a request is made to the endpoint.

Comment: It works!!!!! Thanks for all your help :) One last question if I may, I have just been informed that I need to collect a result that the web service passes back. I thought it would be as simply as assigning the 'result' variable to an SSIS variable, but that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39358/discussion-between-chris-p-and-jeastham1993)

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I made the schoolboy error of having the same my variables readwriting incorrectly.

Thanks a lot for you all your help, really apprecaite it :)